# How to get the form object using jquery when using twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a model object from twitter bootstrap which is as follows

```
        <!-- Name Edit div -->
<div id="form-content" class="modal hide fade in" tabindex="-1">
  <form name="form" action="<c:url value="/editname" />" method="post">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4>Edit Name</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <ul class="nav nav-list">
            <li class="nav-header">First Name</li>
            <li><input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" id="firstName" class="input-xlarge help-inline"></li>
            <li class="nav-header">Last Name</li>
            <li><input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="input-xlarge help-inline"></li>
         </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
       <button id="submit"  class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
       <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

and my ajax script is like follows:

```
$(function() {
    //twitter bootstrap script
    $("button#submit").click(function(){
        var $form = $(this).closest("form").attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
                $("#thanks").html(msg);
                $("#form-content").modal('hide');
            },
            error: function(){
                //alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But the request is not firing. I checked in firebug and it looks like it's not able to get the form object and the request is not going to the controller. How can i make it work. I will have multiple forms in the same page in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you use the `.submit()` function:

```
$(function() {
    $('#form_id').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
          type: form.attr('method'),
          url: form.attr('action'),
          data: form.serialize(),
          success: function(msg){
            $("#thanks").html(msg);
            $("#form-content").modal('hide');    
          },
          error: function(){
            //alert("failure");
          }
        });
    });
});
```

Set the form id to something and change the javascript to match

You can also add a `data-ajax="true"`to all the forms you want to submit bia ajax and then use:

```
var forms = $('form[data-ajax="true"]');
forms.submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // do ajax
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<form name="form" action="<c:url value="/editname" />" method="post">
```

One thing is that you did not given a id for form.

var $form = $(this).closest("form").attr('id');

And if the id exist(if u adding it through code), then above `$form` will contain the id of the form. That is a string.

So use like this,

```
var $form = $(this).closest("form");
```

instead

```
var $form = $(this).closest("form").attr('id');
```

Comment: i modified it but i get this erro "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect." I am using Spring

Answer (score 3):

All HTML form input controls (input, select, button, etc) has a reference to their owner. This makes it possible to do:

```
var $form = $(this.form);
```

But I think oleron´s answer with using `submit` event is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your form doesn't have an id attribute. Give it one and it might work.
so

```
    var $form = $(this).closest("form").attr('id');
```

will not return a value.